# Replace text with HTML value when included in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div's:

```
<div class="message">
   <div class="text-message">:D, :( Hello Wolrd!</div>
</div>
```

I want the result prints this:

```
<div class="message">
   <div class="text-message">
      <div class="smile-happy>":D</div>, 
      <div class="smile-sad">:(</div>  
      Hello Wolrd!
   </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var smile1 = ':)';
var replace = smile1.replace(smile1,'<span class="smile-happy" title="Smile">'+smile1+'</span>');
$(".smile-happy:contains(':D')")){
    $('.smile-happy').replaceWith(replace);
}
```

I really want to just replace the value of smiles `**ex:** :D :(` by a html with specific classes for each smile!

Comment: Can we see some javascript code which you tired??

Comment: post ur jQuery code so that we can see what u hv done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways are there, simply you can try something like this

```js
$('div.text-message').html(function(i,v){
  return v.replace(':D','<div class="smile-happy">:D</div>')
          .replace(':(','<div class="smile-sad">:(</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
   <div class="text-message">:D, :( Hello Wolrd!</div>
</div>
```